# Rendering sample data with "Mustache.js" not getting displayed

Tags: javascript, jquery, templates, mustache

I have a simple code where templating is to be done by Mustache.js, but failing to show anything on screen. There are no errors also in console. Kindly Help!

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mustache.js/2.1.3/mustache.js" ></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var person = {
            firstName: "Christophe",
            lastName: "Coenraets",
            blogURL: "http://coenraets.org"
            };
            var template = "<h1>{{firstName}} {{lastName}}</h1>Blog: {{blogURL}}";
            var html = Mustache.to_html(template, person);
            $('#div1').html(html);
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="#div1"></div>
</body> 
</html>
```

Anyone, can tell where is the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace '#div1' to 'div1' of id attribute in div tag

Comment: Thnx. My mistake ... ;(

Answer (score 1):

http://plnkr.co/edit/m14fkua89UOAjlX506U5?p=preview
    Just replace #div1 to div

```
 <html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mustache.js/2.1.3/mustache.js" ></script>
           <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                var person = {
                firstName: "Christophe",
                lastName: "Coenraets",
                blogURL: "http://coenraets.org"
                };
                var template = "<h1>{{firstName}} {{lastName}}</h1>Blog: {{blogURL}}";
                alert(template);
                var html = Mustache.to_html(template, person);
                alert(html);
                $('#div1').html(html);
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="div1"></div>
    </body> 
    </html>
```